# Remove - before leave a comment on Wordpress Genesis theme

Tags: css, wordpress, comments, shortcode, genesis

I just added the shortcode to add "leave a comment" in the footer of my posts and it shows a dash before. Is there a way to get rid of that dash? I've been Googling and not seeing any answers. [My test site](http://gleefulthings.com/WPtestblog/), I'm using a Genesis child theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the css that is causing that dash.

```
.entry-comments-link::before {
    content: "\2014";
    margin: 0 6px 0 2px;
}
```

In your child theme, simply overwrite it with

```
.entry-comments-link::before {
    content: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perfect answer. I had the same question myself. In addition to overwriting it in the child theme, I was able to use it with the [Simple Custom CSS and JS](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-css-js/) plugin which allows me to preserve the CSS while switching child themes. I don't know if it works with other similar plugins.